# Expanding and discretizing time series data with R and dplyr

Tags: r, time-series, dplyr, tidyverse

I have data from an experiment. We timed human decision making. We have a set of alternaitves (let's call them A,B,C,D) to repeatedly choose from over a 30second period, and we time the first, then second, then Nth choice (subject could change their mind). The data looks like this (time in millisecond):

```
subject time    choice
1       2204    A
1       3673    B
1       8435    C
1       12640   B
1       24031   A
```

I would like to discretize and expand the data, in order to be able to get the option chosen at each second; defaulting to 0 each time there is no choice (yet). Ideally, it would look like this

```
subject second  choice
1       1       0
1       2       0
1       3       A
1       4       B
1       5       B
1       6       B
1       7       B
1       8       B
1       9       C
1       10      C
1       11      C
1       12      C
1       13      B
```

...and so on up to second = 30.

A solution based on the tidyverse packages and dplyr pipes would be most welcome. But I am open to other solutions. Thanks!

Comment: i'm unable to understand the output dataframe. why 2 A's , 5 B's ....?

Comment: ohhh time was in milliseconds!! got it

Comment: @joel.wilson : I know the subject chose A after 2.204 seconds. Hence, at second 1, he had no chocie submitted; at second 2, still no coice (mistake in the output dataset, edited); at second 3, the provisional choice was A; at second 4: he had already switched to B (switch to B happened after 3.673 seconds). And so forth. I need to fill such a table until the 30th second.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(zoo)
df %>%   
  mutate(time=ceiling(time/1000)) %>% 
  complete(subject, time=1:30) %>% 
  group_by(subject) %>% 
  mutate(choice = na.locf(choice, na.rm = FALSE))
```

**data**

```
df = structure(list(subject = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), time = c(2204L, 
3673L, 8435L, 12640L, 24031L), choice = c("A", "B", "C", "B", 
"A")), .Names = c("subject", "time", "choice"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: this is good thanks, but I have troubles in expanding the logic to a situation of multiple subjects on multiple decisions -- as is the case of my data, that has ~200 subjects each on 24 different decision tasks. I am playing around and will approve as soon as I can find a way out! thanks

Comment: @PaoloCrosetto, see the update. It should now work for multiple subjects. hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

This is using Base R approach... may not be that elegant as other answer

```
dt = fread("subject time    choice
1       2204    A
1       3673    B
1       8435    C
1       12640   B
1       24031   A")    

sec <- ceiling(dt$time/1000)
dt1 <- data.table( a = 1:30)
dt1$b <- cumsum(1:30 %in% sec)

x <- dt$choice[dt1$b] 
dt1$ans <- c(rep(0, 30-length(x)), x)

 dt1
     a b ans
 1:  1 0   0
 2:  2 0   0
 3:  3 1   A
 4:  4 2   B
 5:  5 2   B
 .
 .
 .
17: 17 4   B
18: 18 4   B
19: 19 4   B
20: 20 4   B
.
.
.
```